# Using Amazon SES from a windows app

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working on a Windows application that will use Amazon's SES SendRawEmail call. I don't really want to use the secret key on the local machines as they could be anywhere in the world and it could change over time. My plan is to use a REST service on a Linode box generate the x-amzn-authorization header.

Questions:

1. Is this the correct approach to keep the secret key secret?
2. Will the service scale well on a Linode box (a Linode 512)? It's just generating the header.